# PyQGIS get elements from XML

Tags: pyqgis, xml

I wrote a code in VBA for Excel that store in a cell data from a XML like this (https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/reverse?lat=45.387838002000002&lon=7.6777959990000104)
part of the code is:

```
'carichiamo la risposta
    xDoc.Load (url)
    'prendiamo le componenti della risposta
    Set postcode = xDoc.SelectSingleNode("/reversegeocode/addressparts/postcode")
```

Now I'm trying to translate that function to PyQGIS. What I want is to store the same info to specific field but I can't find a way to get information from this XML.

Comment: I would make use of [`lxml`](https://lxml.de/)

Answer (score 1):

As @IanTurton suggests, I would also make use of [lxml](https://pypi.org/project/lxml/), however it's not in the standard library, so here's a way using [xml.etree.ElementTree](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#example) which is in the standard library.

```py
from urllib.request import urlopen
import xml.etree.ElementTree as et

with urlopen('https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/reverse?lat=45.387838002000002&lon=7.6777959990000104') as f:
    tree = et.parse(f)
    postcode = tree.find("./addressparts/postcode").text
```

Comment: Thank for your answer. I didn't test it because i found another way that works well:            for f in newLyr2.selectedFeatures():
                context.setFeature(f)
                ricerca = '">(.+?)</result>'
                urlRich = expr1.evaluate(context)
                if re.search(ricerca, str(urlopen(urlRich).read())) is None: txt =''
                else: txt =re.search(ricerca, str(urlopen(urlRich).read())).group(1).split('">')[1]
                attr_map[f.id()] = {newLyr2.fields().indexFromName("B2full"): txt}
        pass